# Can I use statistical test in EDA for feature selection?

Tags: r, predictive-models, statistical-learning

Can I use the the various statistical tests like chisq, t-test, anova, Mann-whitney, Kruskal-wallis tests for feature selection in predictive modeling. ?

For example ,

I used the etitanic dataset of library earth in R.

```
library(earth)

data("etitanic")

# pclass variable

head(etitanic)
```

The dataset looks like this

```
 pclass survived    sex     age sibsp parch
1    1st        1 female 29.0000     0     0
2    1st        1   male  0.9167     1     2
3    1st        0 female  2.0000     1     2
4    1st        0   male 30.0000     1     2
5    1st        0 female 25.0000     1     2
6    1st        1   male 48.0000     0     0
```

survived is the dependent variable.

```
# Feature selection

# Chisquare test for p-class variable

chisq.test(table(etitanic$pclass, etitanic$survived))
```

The output looks like this

```
Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  table(etitanic$pclass, etitanic$survived)
X-squared = 107.5, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

So as the p-value is less than 0.05, the pclass variable is thought to be signifiant and can be used in prediction of survival in titanic dataset.

Am I correct in using the above stated statistical tests in the exploratory data analysis to find the importance of each variable.

Is it necessary in the eda to perform the statistical tests on each independent variable and dependent variable to find the singificant independent variables.

Feature selection using statistical methods is best approach or not, is there any other best methods.