# Is it accepted to use statistical test in EDA for feature selection?

Tags: feature-selection, exploratory-data-analysis

This question has been already asked [Can I use statistical test in EDA for feature selection?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236531/can-i-use-statistical-test-in-eda-for-feature-selection)  but nobody has answered. Just posted it again as I've also gone through same situation.

Comment: There are various approaches for feature selection. Which statistical test are you thinking?

Comment: @ketan I'm looking for correlation test but what I need to do in case of continuous vs categorical variables?

Comment: @ketan okey thanks. One more thing in order to check dependency of predictors and target variable is the correlation is sufficient just as done in this link <https://www.kaggle.com/poonaml/house-prices-data-exploration-and-visualisation> here only correlation test is performed irrespective to the datatypes. As far I studied that for categorical vs continuous we need to perform ANOVA test and for categorical vs categorical we need to perform chi square. where we actually need this? Thanks in advance

Comment: you are right that ANOVA is used for cat vs cont and chi-sq for cat vc cat. But because in real world the normality assumptions do not hold, people do not use this a lot. This is also why cat variable selection is problemmatic. What people usually do to eliminate redundant cat vars is by checking the cross tabs/box plots for such vars in the data. For example, almost identical boxplots (vs. cont output) for various categories mean that you can ignore such categories.

Answer (score 1):

1. This should be helpful for tests. Answers your
   categorical/quantitative features
   https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/feature-selection-1.html
2. If the features are not too many, you can run cross-validation on
   sub-models using all possible feature sets and select the one which
   minimizes generalization error.
3. You can use *SKLearn's
   Random Forest*. It's `feature_importances_` field gives the most
   important features categorical/quantitative.